# Null pointer exception ,View.findViewById returning null

Tags: android

I have the following code

```
 emailEditText=(MultiAutoCompleteTextView )view.findViewById(R.id.email_editText_auto);
        emailEditText.setThreshold(1);
        emailEditText.setAdapter(adapter);
        emailEditText.setTokenizer(new MultiAutoCompleteTextView.CommaTokenizer() );
```

This works fine in phones but when i use this in Nexus 7 then I get a null value for emailEditText .Any suggestions?

Comment: don't you have a layout-xhdpi defined where you would not have put the email_editText_auto ?

Comment: I have no other idea, if it works on real device except a tablet, I would bet hard on a layout issue but I will let someone else help you.

Comment: @Poutrathor Thanx man, I was using a layout-large which I total forgot about .Fixed it fro there.Thankx again

Comment: you are welcome, trying to help when I can ;)

Answer (score 0):

Are you using different layouts? Be sure all your EditTexts different layouts have the same id.